# Where is the static version of libudev?

Tags: udev, static-linking

Because [I want my binaries to run on older distributions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376449/why-is-a-21-10-built-binary-not-compatible-with-21-04-install), I decided to build a statically linked binary.

My application depends on **libhid-hidraw** and through that, on **libudev**.

I have the development packages installed:

```
sudo apt install libudev-dev libhidapi-dev
```

When I try to link, I get this error:

```
cc -g -Wall -Wextra -static daemon/turboledzd.c -o daemon/turboledzd -lhidapi-hidraw -ludev
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ludev
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

On my system, there is a `libhidapi-hidraw.a` file present:

```
$ dpkg -S hidraw.a
libhidapi-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhidapi-hidraw.a
```

But no such static library for udev:

```
$ dpkg -S libudev.
libudev1:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1
libudev-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libudev.pc
python3-pyudev: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyudev/_ctypeslib/libudev.py
libudev1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.7.1
libudev-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so
libudev1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1
libudev-dev:amd64: /usr/include/libudev.h
libudev1:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.7.1
libudev-dev:amd64: /usr/share/man/man3/libudev.3.gz
```

Which Ubuntu package will contain the `libudev.a` library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is not available upstream and at Debian either.

Here is a related [bug report #915566 in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=915566) and they end up not implementing solution due to the large resulting static files and no demand from users.

It is part of `systemd`, you will able to compile it using these flags:  `-Dstatic-libsystemd=true -Dstatic-libudev=true` . See referenced bug report.